# Adding the XAML file in ASP.NET web Application

Tags: wpf, xaml

How do I add a XAML file to an ASP.NET web page?

Comment: You really need to clarify the question...

Answer (score 1):

Use the Silverlight control:-

```
<object type="application/x-silverlight" width="100%" height="100%" id="slc">
    <param name="source" value="/myfolder/myfile.xaml"/>
 </object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do with that XAML file. :-)

If you want to use it with Silverlight, you need to [learn how to write SL applications](http://silverlight.net/GetStarted/).

If you want to generate a static picture from the XAML to send to the client, you can look at [this blog post](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2008/10/10/converting-and-customizing-xaml-to-png-with-server-side-wpf.aspx).